# In M.U.G.E.N, how do I resize the background in the select screen page?

Tags: pc, mugen

Hopefully you guys know what M.U.G.E.N is, but I'm going to explain to the people that don't. It's basically a two-dimensional fighting game where you put your own fighters, stages, music, backgrounds and so on.

Anyway, recently I got the Black Rock Shooter Screenpack. Everything was fine, but the Selection menu had the background too zoomed in. This caused the picture in the background to appear bigger, and also causing the characters to not appear.

[Here is shows how the screenpack is supposed to look like.](http://mugenguild.com/forumx/index.php?topic=113478.msg1079842#msg1079842)

I used my older winmugen to add the missing stuff to the screenpack, like chars., stages, the application itself, etc..

I have been told that I needed to resize everything, but what do I really resize? I know about the select and system file in the data folder, but I don't know what to really look for.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some fun with M.U.G.E.N a long time ago, maybe I can help a little.

Do you really want to resize the background image or configure it is enough?

For the both ways, you will need to edit the file 'data/system.def'. I'll explain later.

Hard way
You can edit the .ssf used for background or create a new one. I can't remember names now, but I hope you can find some editors.

Easy way
Just customize the actual background image to fit your needs. It's easy and the result is very cool. You can configure the screen with 'tile' and/or 'velocity'.

Edit the data/system.def with any text editor (notepad) and look for the '[SelectBGdef]' section. Follows a sample:

```
;-----------------------
;Character select screen background
[SelectBGdef]
;spr = graphics/selectbg.sff  ;Filename of sprite data

[SelectBG 0] ;Scrolling background
type  = normal
spriteno = 100,0
layerno = 0
start = 0,0
tile  = 1,1
velocity = -1, -1

[SelectBG 1] ;Dark box
type  = normal
spriteno = 100,1
layerno = 0
start = 0, 166
delta = 0,0
tile  = 1,0
trans = sub
window = 85,0, 235,239
velocity = -1, 0

...
```

I grabbed this config from the default installation.
You can change the screen background image with your own:

```
spr = graphics/selectbg.sff
```

Customize:
Each section ('[SelectBG 0]', '[SelectBG 1]') is an image and you can change their properties: tile, velocity, window and so.

Play with the settings, it's really fun.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the tile and velocity does to the background? Oh, and I'm going to try what you have posted. I hope you're right. :D

Comment: Tile is to repeat the same image horizontally or vertically. Set the value to 1 to repeat. One of the values is for the vertical and the other is for horizontal repeat (sorry, I can't remember).

Velocity is a cool feature that allows the image to move. The value -1 is to go backward, 0 to keep still and 1 to move forward. Again, one of the values is to move vertically and the other is to move horizontally.

Comment: Actually I found out the real reason why it didn't work. I used a high-res screenpack on a low-res mugen. Thanks for the help though. :)